# Overriding Concept in Abstract Classes with code example in c#

Tags: oop, polymorphism, abstract-class, overriding

I am trying to access the object of my RepositoryJournalVoucher.cs class from my main class named RepositoryVoucher.cs but i am unable to access or make instance, dont know why.

abstract class RepositoryUniversalAccounts.cs

```
namespace eCartDynamic.RepositoryApplication
{
    public abstract class RepositoryUniversalAccounts
    {
        public string AccountCode { get; set; }
        public abstract string PostVoucher();
    }
}
```

RepositoryCashVoucher.cs

```
namespace eCartDynamic.RepositoryApplication
{
    public class RepositoryCashVoucher : RepositoryUniversalAccounts
    {
        public override string PostVoucher()
        {
            AccountCode = "16-01-001-01-000001-CV";
            return "CV Posted Sucessfully";
        }
    }
}
```

RepositoryJournalVoucher.cs

```
namespace eCartDynamic.RepositoryApplication
{
    public class RepositoryJournalVoucher : RepositoryUniversalAccounts
    {
        public override string PostVoucher()
        {
            AccountCode = "16-01-001-01-000001-JV";
            return "JV Posted Sucessfully";
        }
    }
}
```

Main Class. RepositoryVoucher.cs

```
namespace eCartDynamic.RepositoryApplication
{
    public class RepositoryVoucher
    {
        RepositoryUniversalAccounts abc = new RepositoryJournalVoucher();

    }
}
```

in my RepositoryVoucher.cs Class i am not be able to make object of anything like:

RepositoryUniversalAccounts abc = new RepositoryJournalVoucher();
   RepositoryJournalVoucherabc obj = new RepositoryJournalVoucher();

Comment: what do you mean you "i am not be able to make object of anything like"? Do you get compilation or runtime error?

Comment: copied and pasted your code into a c# Project, and it run fine:

[TestMethod()]
 public void TestRep() {
  RepositoryVoucher vc = new RepositoryVoucher();
  RepositoryUniversalAccounts abc = new RepositoryJournalVoucher(); 
  RepositoryJournalVoucher obj = new RepositoryJournalVoucher();
 }